# remove last delimiter in sed/awk/perl

Tags: perl, awk, sed

An input file is given, each line of which contains delimited data with extra delimiter at the end in data/header with or without enclosures.

Extra delimiter at the end it can contain with/without spaces.

Scenario 1 : Header & Data contain extra delimiter at the end

```
eno|ename|address|
A|B|C|
D|E|F|
```

Scenario 2 : Header doesn't contain extra delimiter at the end

```
eno|ename|address
A|B|C|
D|E|F|
```

Scenario 3 : With enclosures

```
eno|ename|address|
1|2|"A"|
```

Final output has to be like

Scenario 1 :

```
eno|ename|address
A|B|C
D|E|F
```

Scenario 2 :

```
eno|ename|address
A|B|C
D|E|F
```

Scenario 3 :

```
eno|ename|address
1|2|"A"
```

Solution which i have tried so far. But below solution won't work for all three scenarios is there anyway which i can make single command to support all the three scenarios in Sed/Awk/Perl

```
perl -pne 's/(.*)\|/$1/' filename
```

Comment: Use one of `-p` or `-n` but not both.

Comment: @glenn jackman. You can use both. It's simply unecessary because using `-p` turns on `-n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{gsub(/\|$|\| +$/,"")} 1'  Input_file
```

Explanation:

`gsub` is `awk` function which Globally substitute matched pattern with mentioned value.

***Explanation of regex:***

`/\|$|\| +$/`:  Here there are 2 parts of regex. First is `/\|$` and second is `+$` which is segrigated with `|` where 1st regex is for removing `|` from last of the line and second regex removes `|` with space at last. So it basically takes care of both conditions successfully.

Comment: This works as per the above scenarios. I see in your command three pipes has enclosed awk '{gsub(/\|$|\| +$/,"")} 1' . In the command how can i figure it out which position is delimiter

Comment: @user1485267, so `|` when it is escaped by doing `\|` it means we are letting `awk` know that look for exact character `|` and when I am mentioning  only `|` means use either previous regex mentioned before it or use regex mentioned after it, like an OR condition. Lemme know in case of any queries please?

Comment: @user1485267, I have added explanation of it successfully now, kindly go through it and lemme know in case of any queries.

Comment: Thanks Ravinder for detailed explanation

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -lpe 's/\|\s*$//' file
```

will do it. That only removes pipes followed by optional whitespace at the end of each line. Note the `$` line anchor.

I added the `-l` since each line's newline will get removes by the `s///` command, and `-l` will put it back.

Comment: `perl -pe's/\|\h*$//'`

Answer (score 2):

All you need is this:

```
sed 's/|$//'
```

Comment: 2019-10-22. The day sed > awk.

Comment: Doesn't work if there's trailing whitespace, which I think they OP said is possible.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more generic. Let's assume you have the same problem, but with different field separators in different files. Some of these field separators are regular expressions (e.g. a sequence of blanks), others are just a single character `c`. With a tiny little awk program you can get far:

```
# remove_last_empty_field.awk
# 1. Get the correct `fs`
BEGIN { fs=FS; if(length(FS)==1) fs=(FS==" ") ? "[[:blank:]]+" : "["FS"]" }
# remove the empty field
{ sub(fs"$","") }
# Print the current record
1
```

Now you can run this on your various files as:

```
$ awk -f remove_last_empty_field.awk f1.txt
$ awk -f remove_last_empty_field.awk FS="|" f2.txt
$ awk -f remove_last_empty_field.awk FS="[|.*]" f3.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pi -e 's/\|$//' Your_FIle
```